# If $f:R\to S$ is a surjective homomorphism of integral domains, $p$ is irreducible in $R,$ and $f(p)\neq 0_R$ is $f(p)$ irreducible in $S?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, euclidean-domain

*Background:*

**Exercise 24:**  If $f:R\to S$ is a surjective homomorphism of integral domains, $p$ is irreducible in $R,$ and $f(p)\neq 0_R$ is $f(p)$ irreducible in $S?$

*Questions:*

My guess is no. If we let $p=6,$ and $f:\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}_6,$ and $f(2\cdot 2)=[2]_6\cdot [2]_6=[4]_6.$  I am wondering what happens if $p$ being prime, would the result hold?

Thank you in advance

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151253/discussion-on-question-by-seth-if-fr-to-s-is-a-surjective-homomorphism-of-int); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Take $\pi:K[X,Y,Z]\to K[X,Y,Z]/(YZ-X)$ the canonical projection. 
Clearly $X$ is irreducible in $K[X,Y,Z]$ but $\overline{X}=\overline{Y}\overline{Z}$.

Comment: I'm not sure I've understood your comment. In this case $f$ is just the canonical projection on the quotient ring, so you may as well read $f(X)=\bar{X}$

Comment: I've changed notations so it may sound more familiar now

Comment: @Temoi Is it clear that neither $\overline{X}$ nor $\overline{Y}$ are units in the quotient?

Comment: @Temoi thank you for the example and changing the notation.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Suppose $\overline{Y}$ is a unit. Then you have polynomials $f,g$ such that $Yf-1=(YZ-X)g$ in $K[X,Y,Z]$ which is clearly impossibile for degree reasons. It should be similar for $X$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven $K[X,Y,Z] / (YZ - X) \simeq K[\bar Y, \bar Z]$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler and Temoi. Thanks, my (commutative) algebra is a bit rusty. That clears things up.

Comment: @Temoi I am not familar with multivariable polynomial. Do I just plug in $$ into $$ and out comes $+\langle −\rangle?$ (I am reposting my earlier comment, since there was a typo in the math of my question.)

Answer (score 0):

Each prime number $p$ is irreducible in $\mathbf Z[x]$. The evaluation homomorphism $\mathbf Z[x] \to \mathbf Z$ where $x \mapsto p$ is surjective and it maps the irreducible polynomial $x^n + p$ in $\mathbf Z[x]$, where $n \geq 1$, to the integer $p^n + p = p(p^{n-1} + p)$, which is composite.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{Z}[x]\mapsto \mathbb{Z}$, $x\mapsto 0$, surjective, $x+a$ irreducible, maps to $a$, which can be any element.