# Is this the correct negation of the definition and criterias for Irreducible elements in integral domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, definition, integral-domain

*Background:*

**Definition:**

If $R$ is an integral domain, $p\in R$ is called an **irreducible element** (and is said to be **irreducible** in $R$) if it satisfies the following conditions:

*(1)* $p\neq 0$ and $p$ is not a unit

*(2)* if $p=ab$ in $R,$ then $a$ or $b$ is a unit in $R$.

An element that is not irreducible is called **reducible.**

**Theorem 10.7**  Let $R$ be a Euclidean domain.  Every nonzero, nonunit element of $R$ is the product of irreducible elements, and this factorization is unique up to associates; that is, if

$$p_1p_2\cdots p_r=q_1q_2\cdots q_s$$

with each $p_i$ and $q_i$ irreducible, then $r=s$ and, after reordering and relabeling if necessary,

$$p_i \text{ is an associate of } q_j \text{ for }j=1,2,\ldots r.$$

> Proof:  Let $S$ be the set of all nonzero nonunit elements of $R$ that are $\textit{not}$ the product of irreducibles.  we shall show that $S$ is empty, which proves that every njonzero nonunit element has at least one factorization as a product of irreduciblees.  SUppose, on the contrary, that $S$ is nonempty.  then the set $\{\delta(s)\mid s\in S\}$ is a nonempty set of nonnegative integers, which contains a smallest element by the Well-Ordering Axiom.  That is, there exists $a\in S$ such that
>
> $$(*)\quad\quad \delta(a)\leq \delta(s)\quad \text{ for every } s\in S.$$
>
> Since $a\in S,a$ is not itself irreducible.  By the definition of irreducibility, $a=bc$ with both $b$ and $c$ nonunits.....

*Questions:*

I posted several questions about irreducible elements in integral domain, like [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4853423/if-fr-to-s-is-a-surjective-homomorphism-of-integral-domains-p-is-irreducib)  I thought I would create a separate post just to clarify if I am understanding the negation of the definition correctly.  For the definition of irreducible for an element $p$ in an integral domain $R$ quoted above, it requires $p$ to satistify both conditions *(1)*, and *(2)* above simultaneously.  But for an element $r\in R,$ to be not an irreducible element.  **Is it correct **to have either one of the following two possibilities:

Scenario $(1)$: $r$ is a unit.

Scenario $(2)$: $r$ is not a unit, and for $a,b\in R$, $r=ab$ where both $a$ is not a unit and $b$ is not a unit.

If $r\in R$ statistifies either of sceneraio $1$ or $2$, then $r$ is consider to be not irreducible.

The question and example in the [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4853423/if-fr-to-s-is-a-surjective-homomorphism-of-integral-domains-p-is-irreducib) i linked; the natural homomorphism: $f(a)=[a]_p,$ for $p$ prime where every elements $f(a)\in \mathbb{Z}_p$ is not irreducible satisfies sceneario (1) above and theorem 10.7 above, where the diviosrs of $a$ haveing both of its factors $b,c$ both being nonunits which satisfies sceneario (2) above.

**I would** like to know if my negation of definiton of irreducible elements and the two sceneraios above would be consider as critieras, scenerio (1) and (2) above for an element to be consider as "not irreduciblee" if such an element satisfies either one of them.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In integral domains the condition $(1)$ is usually presented as *scope*, i.e. the definition only applies to nonzero nonunits. In more general rings (with zero-divisors) it may be useful to expand the scope.

Comment: @BillDubuque there is a theorem in Hungerford where it says that every non zero nonunit $p$ is the product of irreducible elements.  In the proof, it define "$S$ to be the set of non zero non unit elements of $R$ that are not the product of irreducible." Later on in the proof, it says, "let $a\in R,$ $a$ itself is not irreducible, by definition of of irreducibility, $a=bc,$ with both $b$ and $c$ being non units." So $a$ here satisfies scenario (2), hence they are not irreducible above....

Comment: @BillDubuque also, according to this recent [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4853423/if-fr-to-s-is-a-surjective-homomorphism-of-integral-domains-p-is-irreducib) the counter example is $f(a)=[a]_p$ where $p$ is prime.  Every element in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ are units, so they satisfy sceneraio (1) above hence these elements are not irreducible.  Am I correct in my understanding the negation of the definition of irreducible?  I an also going by what Arturo wrote in that other post.

Comment: Your negation looks correct!

Comment: @Mathmo123 if I have an element in an integral domain and it satisfies either scenario (1) or (2) above, then it is not irreducible?

Comment: That's the correct logical negation of the statement. But the point is that "reducible" is not equivalent to "not irreducible" in all of $R$ because both are restricted to nonzero nonunits, i.e. $R$ is the disjoint union of $\{0\}$ and units and irreducibles and reducibles.

Comment: @BillDubuque "reducible" mean it can be factored.  I just want to make sure I know the criterias when an element is not irreducible.  That is why I am asking if either scenario (1) and (2) are the proper and only criterias?

Comment: **Again:** Mathjax is **not** for formatting text. Stop it.

Comment: @BillDubuque I edited my question, can you check if it is a bit more clear.  I also added concrete examples from my explainations I gave to you in the comments